# AWS: Placing an Application Load Balance in front of Elasticsearch Managed Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, load-balancing, aws-alb

I am creating an elasticsearch managed service on AWS;

When creating the service, no explicit instances are created and you are just given a url/endpoint;

I want to expose the service via an ALB, but when creating the corresponding target groups, I am forced to choose between `instance` and `ip`, while the only thing I have is an endpoint (`url`);

How to go about this?

Comment: There is an option to configure redirect to another URL with Listener rules. Is it a way to go for you?

Comment: any updates about this? I'm facing the same issue and unable to access kibana via the browser

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is currently possible (3rd Jun 2019). @michail_c mentioned the redirect option but unfortunately that won't help as it just returns a redirect response to a client, but the ES domain isn't public (assuming a VPC domain).

The easiest thing to do would be setting up an EC2 instance to proxy requests. I've been playing with using lambda as a proxy (but still have some kinks to work out with that approach)

Comment: Curious how you travelled using lambda to proxy? Assuming it's a lambda in behind an ALB?

Comment: @Anntoin Wilkinson, can you have a guide on how to setup and EC2 to proxy requests? I'm facing the same issue and I need to expose the kibana endpoint of elasticsearch so it can be reachable from the browser.